# BigQuery: Create a new table by combining few columns from two other tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new table from two other tables that consists of few common columns in BigQuery. My approach is using UNION. Here is the sample SQL written for the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `Temp` AS
SELECT proNum, column2, column3, column4,column5,column6, column7, column8, column9 FROM
(
(SELECT t1.proNum, column2, column3, column4, sysInf.loadedAt AS column5, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.proNum ORDER BY t1.sysInf.loadedAt DESC) AS system_rank
 FROM `table1` t1) WHERE system_rank = 1
 UNION
(SELECT t2.proNum, column6,column7, column8,sysInf.loadedAt AS column9, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.proNum ORDER BY t2.sysInf.loadedAt DESC) AS change_rank
FROM `table2` t2) WHERE channge_rank = 1
```

proNum from table 1 and proNum,column6,column7 from table 2 are the unique keys.

The task is to combine table 1 and 2 with the above mentioned columns and create a new table without duplicates and the new table should have one record per proNum(because 2 records can have same proNum) and the proNum should be arranged in descending order

I am unable to figure out what is the syntax error here. The syntax error thrown is: Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi OP, can you please provide sample data and sample output of how your expected table/output will look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things going on here:

1. Your `WHERE system_rank = 1` and `WHERE change_rank = 1` are outside of your queries.  This is causing the error in your question.
2. However, you cannot simply move them inside (ie `` FROM `table` t1 WHERE system_rank = 1 ``) because your `WHERE` is trying to filter data *before* the `ROW_NUMBER()` column is created.
3. Your outer `SELECT` is referencing columns that aren't available because you are unioning different columns together (that won't work either).

If I were writing this (assuming logic is correct):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset.temp` AS
(
    with 
        t1 as (select proNum, column2, column3, column4, sysInf.loadedAt as column5, null as column6, null as column7, null as column8, null as column9, row_number() over (partition by proNum order by sysInf.loadedAt desc) as system_rank from `table1`),
        t2 as (select proNum, null as column2, null as column3, null as column4, null as column5, column6, column7, column8, sysInf.loadedAt as column9, row_number() over (partition by proNum order by sysInf.loadedAt desc) as change_rank from `table2`),
        filtered_t1 as (select * except(system_rank) from t1 where system_rank = 1),
        filtered_t2 as (select * except(change_rank) from t2 where change_rank = 1),
        unioned as (select * from filtered_t1 union all select * from filtered_t2)
        select * from unioned
)
```

I am explicitly creating null columns to keep the `column2`-`column9` pattern.  However, if columns 2-5 map to columns 6-9, consider aliasing the columns then unioning those to reduce the # of columns you are keeping.